# Swipable Cell in static UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I have a static `UITableView` (created in storyboard) with a fix amount of sections and cells. Now, I'd like to make one specific cell swipable. I don't want to delete the row, I just want to display a print button where normally is the delete button when swiping a cell in a non-static `UITableView` .

How do I make exactly one cell in my static `UITableView` swipable?

Answer (score 3):

U can add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on top the cell:

```
//The setup code (in viewDidLoad in your view controller)
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = 
  [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

//The event handling method
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

  //Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: This works but how to I swipe the cell. I want to move the cell left when the user swipes, like the normal UITableView delete row behaviour. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Static is static ;) U shouldn't want to delete it. Why don't u use dynamic cells??? Any way, u can achieve this by view on top red view with delete label Etc...

Comment: I don't want to delete the row, I just want to move the cell as the user swipes it and display a button that is like the normal delete button, but this button has a specific action attached to it

Comment: So, add gesture recognition on top UIView, and underneath add UILabel and so on.. try to track the dynamic cell appearance and behaviour. No easy way here...